# Python: Kill Subprocess Only If Process Goes Interactive

Tags: process, python

I need to test a process in a loop with different input. In my circumstance, if it does not go interactive it has succeeded. If it does go interactive, I must conitinue on testing and kill the process that went interactive.

I've tried several approaches but nothing has worked. This seems to be working partially, but it tends to freeze up the computer on exit with thousands of rounds done.

```
for filePath in filePaths:
    counter += 1
    command = "".join([components[0], '', components[1], filePath[:-1] + ' ', components[3]])
    print "round: " + str(counter)
    print "command", command

    subProcess = subprocess.Popen("exec " + command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = subProcess.stdout.readline()
    if len(output):
        print ["went interactive:",output]
        subProcess.kill()
    else:
        print "non-interactive"
        sys.exit()
```

Could someone help me get this code snippet to work?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the subprocess's standard input to /dev/null, so that the interaction gets end-of-file and exits?

Comment: @ stolenmoment Maybe thousands of process are not exiting because I'm not doing this? Would you see my updated question?

Comment: Pass stdin=open('/dev/null', 'r') to give the subprocess an EOF on stdin.  Your code will judge the sub as "interactive" if it prints anything; is this correct?  If so, you should subProcess.kill() (perhaps redundant) and subProcess.wait() *before* checking the length of output, to dispose of the dead sub.  If this isn't Unix, then you get to figure out the local equivalent of /dev/null.